# Center EditText when SoftKeyboard appears

Tags: android, scrollview, centering, soft-keyboard

I have an activity with some EditText and I want to center the selected EditText when the Sofkeyboard appears. Currently when the softkeyboard appears push up my EditText but I want to see this EditText centered between top and softkeyboard.

How It should be
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzp7j.jpg]

I allready have android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize" in my manifest to allow scroll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I tried to scroll dynamical the view but I can't get the current position of the EditText respect the softkeyboard

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your Manifest.xml

Comment: @JoanColmenero thank you, but I got the same result. If I select a EditText at the bottom of the screen, the view auto scroll and shows the Edittext just above the soft keyboard, and I wanta to see the next EditText with the selected EditText in the middle of the screen